# Unable to Login with Facebook even with Admin account Facebook says "Unsupported Request" in react native mobile application

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

I am facing an error with Facebook's Login API. My app is actually disabled by Facebook due to a violation of **Facebook Platform Policy clause 6.1,** which says `your app is crashing while trying to log in with Facebook`. For that I also have filed an appeal but the issue I am facing is I am unable to log in even with my admin account due to which I cannot test the app and can't find where the app is crashing. When I am trying to log in with my Admin account Facebook says **"Unsupported Request"**.

[image: Facebook Login Issue]

Kindly guide me if anyone else has faced this sort of issue and has resolved it.